# D language import local module

Tags: d, .so, dmd, dub

I am new to D language. i have a project `A`. When i executed `dub build` it has created me `libA.so`.  i am trying to create a different .d file and import this module.

now i wanted to write a D wrapper to consume it.

when i tried

`import a`

it did not work. i copied the `libA.so` to the `sudo cp libA.so /usr/include/dmd/druntime/import/` but the import did not work.

Can you please help me how can i import this ?

Comment: You need D source files to be available when compiling the program, in the same way how you need C header files for libraries to be available when compiling C programs.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for writing and using shared libraries in D on Linux is here:

https://dlang.org/articles/dll-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't import shared libraries in D. You import modules (source files). So the .so file does not belong in the import directory. You need to *link* to that. `import a` means the compiler will search the import path for `a.d`. That's what needs to be in your import directory. If your library has multiple source files, they each need to be on the import path and imported separately.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you want to create a library via dub, and then use that library in another project. Is that correct?

For example, your project may have a structure like:

```
myProject
├- commonLib
|
├- program1
|  (depends on commonLib)
└- program2
   (depends on commonLib)
```

If this is what you are trying to do, you should consider using Dub [sub-packages](https://dub.pm/package-format-sdl.html#sub-packages).

For example, `myProject/dub.sdl` might look like this:

```
name "myProject"
targetType "none"
dependency "myProject:common" path="."
dependency "myProject:program1" path="."
dependency "myProject:program2" path="."
subPackage "./common/"
subPackage "./program1/"
subPackage "./program2/"
```

Your common library at `myProject/common/dub.sdl` may look like this:

```
name "common"
targetType "library"
```

And finally you would depend on it like this in `myProject/program1/dub.sdl`:

```
name "program1"
targetType "executable"
dependency "myProject:common" path="../"
```